# How to deal with complexity in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I build pretty big app using Laravel and Vue.js 2.

I have many different forms in this app. Every form has different types of inputs (text, date (using datetimepicker), coordinates (using google maps), select, files).

The problem is: I write every type of input as separate component.

It's ok, because there many fields, but few of field's types.

But code for forms becomes large, because I have to write functions in every form which collect data from underlying inputs (using @changed event on them).

May be there is a better way?

P.S.

Example of `universal` input which can handle different types of `real` inputs http://pastebin.com/8zkAKysg

Comment: Can you add some code samples as well of these components?

Comment: A minimal example of working code would allow us to figure out where things could be better.